# Rails Net::OpenTimeout - execution expired: when sending mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, smtp, sendmail, actionmailer

When sending mail in Rails using *ActionMailer* I am getting following error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5222.3ms

OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError - SSL_read: wrong version number:
```

My setting in development.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  ActionMailer::Base.default :from => Settings.mail.alerts
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address => "smtp.live.com",
      :port => 587,
      :domain => "xyz.in",
      :user_name => "alerts@xyz.in",
      :password => "my_password",
      :authentication => "plain",
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

I am stuck on this issue for 4 days. Any help would be appreciated.
[here](http://justpaste.it/f08b) is the full stack-trace

**EDIT**

mail gem => actionmailer (3.2.17)

Settings.mail.alerts => 'alerts@xyz.in'

And If I use any other provider like gmail it's working fine but in this case only it is showing this error.

Comment: http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html did you follow this ?

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: what is your mail gem version ? https://github.com/mikel/mail/commit/2a524126fe88996288c527cbd8ecb3af2844f154 Please check it in your mail gem

Comment: ` context.ssl_version = :SSLv3` it should be there

Comment: `Settings.mail.alerts` it should be an email like "test@example.com"

Comment: @RajarshiDas thanx for your time. I have updated my question with details... still no luck so far

Comment: did you check you mail gem ? as I stated above what does it contain ?

Comment: I am not using any particular gem but sending mail via *actionmailer*. How can I check if `actionmailer (3.2.17)` contains ` context.ssl_version = :SSLv3` or not?

Answer (score 1):

Add configuration:

```
ssl: true
```

Test:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address => "smtp.live.com",
      :port => 587,
      :domain => "xyz.in",
      :user_name => "alerts@xyz.in",
      :password => "my_password",
      :authentication => "plain",
      :enable_starttls_auto => true,
      :ssl => true
  }
```